# optimization function

Tags: optimization

If we want to maximize a function $f$ and we know that $f$ depend on 3 variables $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ without knowing the exactly relation between them but we know that maximizing $f$ can be achieved through maximizing $v_1$ and $v_2$ and minimizing $v_3$. My question is can I rewrite max $f$ as max $v_1$+$v_2$ - $v_3$.
thanks

Comment: No, there are many other possibilities such as $2v_1+2v_2-v_3$ or $v_1^2+v2^2-v_3^2$.

Comment: thank you sir for this explanation.